# Extract location information from photos

Tags: android

I'm trying to develop a photo geotagging app.
How do I extract GPS information from geotagged photos, so that i can Tag it into MapView?
Photos are geotagged, which methods and classes should I call to retrieve the information?

Please do tell me if the my question is not clear.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a library that can read EXIF information. Android comes with one: `android.media.ExifInterface`. [Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html).